# How to use context with class in CreateView in django?

Tags: django, django-views

How to use context with class in CreateView in django?

Before i have:

```
#views.py
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from cars.models import *

def CreateCar(CreateView):
    info_sended = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormCar(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            info_sended = True
            form.save()
    else:
        form = FormCar()
    ctx = {'form': form, 'info_sended':info_sended}
    return render_to_response("create_car.html", ctx,
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Now, a have, and try:

```
class CreateCar(CreateView):
    info_sended = False
    template_name = 'create_car.html'
    model = Car
    success_url = 'create_car' #urls name

    def form_valid(self, form):
        info_sended = True
        ctx = {'form': form, 'info_sended':info_sended}
        return super(CreateCar, self).form_valid(form)
```

My html page is:

```
<!-- create_car.html -->
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if info_sended %}
    <p>Data saved successfully</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'list_cars' %}">Show List</a></p>
{% else %}
    <form class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% include "form.html" %}
        <div class="col-md-offset-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 14):

You should define [`get_context_data()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) method in your class view. Update your code as

```
from django.shortcuts import render

class CreateCar(CreateView):
    info_sended = False
    template_name = 'create_car.html'
    model = Car
    success_url = 'create_car' #urls name

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.info_sended = True
        # Instead of return this HttpResponseRedirect, return an 
        #  new rendered page
        super(CreateCar, self).form_valid(form)
        return render(self.request, self.template_name,
                      self.get_context_data(form=form))


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(CreateCar, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['info_sended'] = self.info_sended
        return ctx
```

Comment: Small error in the solution "ctx = return super(CreateCar, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)" should be "ctx = super(CreateCar, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)"

Comment: can we pass the rendered context to form_valid ? i have a question regarding the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56325133/attendance-system-using-django

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [get_context_data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.ContextMixin)

```
class CreateCar(CreateView):
    info_sended = False
    template_name = 'create_car.html'
    model = Car
    success_url = 'create_car' #urls name

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.info_sended = True
        return super(CreateCar, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(CreateCar, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['info_sended'] = self.info_sended
        return ctx
```

If you see the [django source](https://github.com/django) [CreateView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L208) inherits from [BaseCreateView](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L193) this one inherits from [ModelFormMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L88) in turn this one inherits from [FormMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L12) and this one inherits from [ContextMixin](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L16) and the only method this one defines is `get_context_data`.
Hope this helps you.

PD: This may be a bit confusing for better understanding of inheritance in Python feel free of read this [article](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) about MRO.

Comment: ok, i did what you indicated, but did not return the success message. I mean, returns info_sended = True, but not itemized returns the html message.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with but not itemized returns the html message.

Answer (score 0):

Since your are creating a new instance of a Car, there is no context for `get_context_data` because there is no object yet. I didn't test using Mixin to get the context from another class as suggested above, but that seems reasonable. However, if I can assume you want to use the basic `CreateView`, `UpdateView` and `DeleteView`, then I solved this by assuming I will have no context for `CreateView`. Then in my template I used an **if** to make the decision, such as:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value={% if not buttonword %}Save{% else %}{{ buttonword }}{% endif %}>
</form>
```

In `DeleteView` I include:

```
context['buttonword'] = 'Delete'
```

In `UpdateView` I include:

```
context['buttonword'] = 'Update'
```

As I said, I do not set `buttonword` in `CreateView`. Hence, when the template logic is done, if `buttonword` is assigned, the word in it shows up in the button, otherwise Save shows up on the button.