# Django: How to provide context for a FormView?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Newbie Question: I have a FormView which displays a sign-up form, using Django's validations, etc. It all works fine, however, I can't seem to work out how to provide any data (context) to the template. Currently, I have:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from accounts.forms import SignUpForm

class SignUpView(FormView):
    template_name = 'accounts/signup.html'
    form_class = SignUpForm 

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # executes when form validates..
        (...)
        return redirect('/account/')
```

I tried adding some context data via `get()` per below, which I need when the page first displays, which sort of works *except* the input fields of the form are gone (the labels are all there):

```
def get(self, request):
    return render(self.request, self.template_name, {'data': data })
```

Could someone please clarify why that is, and how to get it to work? To put it another way: When using FormView with form_valid(), where do I place code intended for the initial GET request?

Comment: See my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20877455/how-to-use-context-with-class-in-createview-in-django/20878183#20878183

Comment: Thanks! Worked it out though I believe there is an error in that answer: There should be no `return` in `ctx = return super(...)`?

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you, I had not given account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to methods of doing it, if the data is related only to that get view then you can move on:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(SignUpView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    something = something
    context['something'] = something
    return context
```

Or use a Mixin:

```
class SomeMixin(object):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SomeMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        something = something
        context['something'] = something
        return context
```

And then:

```
class SignUpView(SomeMixin, FormView):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        ...
```

Comment: I tried the first approach above but I doesn't look like the context hits the template -- getting `TypeError at /account/signup/ 'NoneType' object is not iterable` (which it should be). Victor's solution above, using `get_context_data(self, **kwargs)` did the trick. Thanks guys!

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake in the first code, it should be get_context_data for the context I am editing it now.